# Where is my downloaded file

Tags: find, wget

I tried to install java runtime with the following commands

```
 su - 
    cd /opt
    wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.rpm"

wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jre-8u45-linux-x64.rpm"
```

The after the download was complete.

```
cd /opt 
rpm -Uvh jdk-8u45-linux-x64.rpm
```

It gives me no such file or directory.

I tried to search for it using this command,

```
find . -name jdk-8u45-linux-x64.rpm
```

It does not exist.  Where can I find the downloaded file ?

Comment: I would try either `rpm -Uvh ./jdk...` or `rpm -Uvh /opt/jdk...`

Comment: 1. For installation, which command gives `no such file or directory`: the `cd` or the `rpm`? 2. What output did you get from the first set of commands? Did `wget` actually download anything? Please [edit] your question to provide the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `wget` command I found the following file name after the download completed.

```
jre-8u45-linux-x64.rpm?AuthParam=1445366776_75a96af45f0e6aafeed6e8fe224c008d
```

Rename the file to `jre-8u45-linux-x64.rpm` and you should be able to execute your `rpm` command.

```
mv jre-8u45-linux-x64.rpm\?AuthParam\=1445366776_75a96af45f0e6aafeed6e8fe224c008d jre-8u45-linux-x64.rpm
```

**EDIT**

Your actual file name may differ.  The above is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the file using

```
find / -name jdk-8u45-linux-x64.rpm
```

It'll search for whole directory structure and return you the value.